# Unexpected jumps/oddities in lubridate and zoo package (reproducible example added)

Tags: r, zoo, lubridate

###### Bug in lubricate & zoo ? ######

```
dataframex <- as.data.frame(rnorm(420,0,1))
dataframex
names(dataframex) <- c("value")

head(dataframex)
library(lubridate); library(zoo) # To assign months to rows of the dataframe
dataframex
row.names(dataframex) <- as.yearmon(seq(ymd('1980-01-01'), by = '1 month', length.out=(420)))
dataframex
```

There appears unexpected jumps/oddities at certain time points that I could not figure out:

```
            value
Oca 1980 -1.112455234
Şub 1980 -0.370769140
.....................
Mar 1995  0.219924804
Nis 1995 -1.46725                value # oddity "value" occurred
Oca 1980 1995 -0.158754605             # unexpected jump from Apr1995 to Jan1980
Tem 1995  1.464587312
......................
Eyl 2010 -0.1995 -0.158754605
Tem 1995  1.464587312           # unexpected jump from Sept2010 to July1995
Ağu 1995 -0.                      # oddity again
Ara 2010  0.277914132
```

So, sometimes "i" is wrongly printed among year labels, sometimes "i" is printed in value labels on the right.

**What I did to solve the problem:**
I suspected it can be a Windows Regional Settings problem. I changed TR-TR to EN-US. Again the same oddities occurred.
I also changed the regional settings to have "." as decimal separator, also tries "," as decimal points. 
The error remained same!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured out that the error is due to the problematic localization language file in Revolution R program.

**The Step-by-Step solution:**
**1.** Change the R localization language to solve the oddity/jump problem:
"Tools - Options - Environment - Help - International Settings - Language:English"
**2.** Restart R so that a new environment exists in R

Then, apply completely the same code above to check whether the oddity/jump problem is solved. If solved, then OK.

If oddity/jump problem is not solved, pass to Step 3 and 4.

**3.** Change the Regional settings from TR-TR to EN-US in Control Panel of Windows.
**4.** Change the International Setting in Revolution R:
"Tools - Options - Environment - Help - International Settings - Language:Same as Microsoft Windows"
**5.** Restart R so that a new environment exists in R

Then, apply completely the same code above. This time no oddity/no jump/no "i" occurs.

**PS:** Revolution R team should correct this language issue in related Turkish localization language files.

Comment: The SOF system says me to wait 2 days for accepting it as answer.

Comment: You should report this to them, rather than suggest they fix it as a postscript to your answer.